# Подскажите, как выразить в sympy функцию C(1,1)

Tags: python, sympy

подскажите, как выразить С(1,1) в sympy в solve . Вообще моя задача составить из Interg1,Interg2,Interg3,Interg4(те же Integ1, но с другим множителем) составить СЛАУ, и мне нужно будет выразить C(1,1),C(2,1),C(2,2),C(1,2). Спасибо большое.

```
from sympy import *
x, y, a, b, D, i, m, n, q = symbols("x y a b D i m n q")
C = Function('C')
w = Function('w')
iparametr = 1
exprw = Sum(Sum(C(n,m)*((1-cos(2*pi*n*x/a))*(1-cos(2*pi*m*y/b))),(n,1,i)),(m,1,i))

exprw = expand(exprw.subs(i, iparametr).doit())
exprx = diff(exprw,x,4)
exprx

expry = diff(exprw,y,4)
expry


exprxy = diff(exprw,y,2)
exprxy = diff(exprxy,x,2)
exprxy


n=1
m=1
Integ1 = integrate(D*((exprx + expry + 2*exprxy)-q)*(1-cos(2*pi*n*x/a))*(1-cos(2*pi*m*y/b)),(x,0,a),(y,0,b))
solve(Integ1, C(1,1) )
```

[image: ://i.stack.imgur.com/aPEhU.png]

Comment: Если С число сочетаний, то для таких аргументов оно равно 1

Comment: C - это функция

Comment: Вопрос не понятен.